# Installing Postgres server 9.6 on Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, yum, rpm, amazon-linux

What's the best way to install postgres-server 9.6 on Amazon Linux without building from source? I tried running `rpm -i https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-ami201503-96-9.6-2.noarch.rpm` to install the version listed on https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php, and it installed without errors, but I still don't have `service postgresql`, or `psql`, or a `postgres` user. What did I miss?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have installed the *repository* that makes PostgreSQL packages available (check `/etc/yum.repos.d`). Now you can do `yum update` and actually install the DB with `yum install postgresql96-server`.

Comment: Quite likely you'll need to do that as root: sudo rpm -i https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-ami201503-96-9.6-2.noarch.rpm

Comment: @Vic: That's quite clearly not the problem.

Comment: Your answer is correct though, as I followed along, I needed to be root. It was the problem for me, and then your instructions were applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [**Sven**'s answer (with **Vic**'s comment)](https://serverfault.com/questions/831962/installing-postgres-server-9-6-on-amazon-linux/831963#831963), you should:

1. Include the official PostgreSQL 9.6 RPM package file

   > `sudo rpm -i https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-ami201503-96-9.6-2.noarch.rpm`
2. Install the needed Postgresql 9.6 packages using yum

   > `sudo yum install postgresql96-server.x86_64`

   This would allow you to install a PostgreSQL server and create a `postgres` user. However, since you've also wanted to install the command line tools for postgres, you will need...

   > `sudo yum install postgresql96.x86_64 postgresql96-libs.x86_64`

   Which installs `psql`, `pg_dump`, and other command line tools.

I know it is too late but I hope that helps anyone who might stumble on this kind of problem.